# Matlab RegEx for specific string pattern

Tags: matlab

I'm working with the following file addresses format:

```
/A/B/C/D/foo/bar
```

I want to come up with a regular expression in Matlab that will return the last word in the adress. In this case I want the word "bar". What would be the regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the file name from the full file path, you can use [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) rather than a regex:

```
>> [path,name,ext] = fileparts('/A/B/C/D/foo/bar')
path = /A/B/C/D/foo
name = bar
ext =
```

If `bar` has an extension, then it would be:

```
>> [path,name,ext] = fileparts('/A/B/C/D/foo/bar.txt')
path = /A/B/C/D/foo
name = bar
ext = .txt
>> nameext = [name ext]
nameext = bar.txt
```